# A Bernoulli trial problem

Tags: probability

In Bernoulli trials with parameter $p$, let $N_n$ be the number of trials required to produce either $n$ successes or $n$ failures, whichever comes first. I would like to computer the probability distribution of $N_n$.

My solution is:

Suppose $S_n$ is the number of trials required to produce $n$ successes.  Then 
$$ P(S_n=k) = {{k-1}\choose{n-1}} (1-p)^{k-n}p^n.$$

Suppose $F_n$ is the number of trials required to produce $n$ failures.  Then 
$$ P(F_n=k) = {{k-1}\choose{n-1}} p^{k-n}(1-p)^n.$$

$N_n = \min\{S_n, F_n\}.$ But I doubt it is correct and even if it is correct, I am not sure how to proceed. Can I get some insights? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $N_n$ can take on values from $n$ to $2n-1$.  For any fixed $k$ in the
range from $n$ to $2n-1$, the event $\{N_n = k\}$ occurs if the $k$-th trial
is a success and the previous $k-1$ trials had $n-1$ successes and $k-n \leq n-1$
failures, OR, the $k$-th trial is a failure and the previous $k-1$ trials had
$n-1$ failures and $k-n \leq n-1$ successes.  Can you find the probability for
each of the two cases?  You will likely have a $\binom{k-1}{n-1}$ in there
somewhere....

Comment: (+1) This is the right approach and gives the right intuition.

Answer (score 1):

[Negative binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) ($NeBi(n,p)$) is the distribution of number of failures in sequence of trials until $n$ successes occur. The expression you seek is

$$
  \mathbb{P}(N_n = k) = \frac{\mathbb{P}( \left. S = k-n \right| S < n) \mathbb{P}(S < n) + \mathbb{P}( \left. F = k-n \right| F < n)\mathbb{P}(F < n)}{ \mathbb{P}(S < n)  + \mathbb{P}(F < n) }
$$ 
where $S$ follows $NeBi(n, p)$ and $F$ follows $NeBi(n, 1-p)$. This gives

$$
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \mathbb{P}(N_n = k) &=& \left( p^n (1-p)^{k-n} \binom{k-1}{n-1} +(1-p)^n p^{k-n} \binom{k-1}{n-1}  \right)  
 \frac{B(n,n) \chi_{n \le k < 2 n}  }{B_p(n,n) + B_{1-p}(n,n) } 
  \end{eqnarray}
$$
where $B_p(a,b)$ is incomplete Beta function.

**Added**: I finally realized that, since $B_{p}(n,n) = \int_0^p (t (1-t))^{n-1} \mathrm{d}  t$, $B_p(n,n) + B_{1-p}(n,n) = \int_0^1 (t (1-t))^{n-1} \mathrm{d}  t = B(n,n)$, so that the normalization factor actually equals to $1$.

Comment: I don't know why those incomplete beta functions are there. And, note that $n \leq k < 2n$ with probability 1, so the characteristic functions aren't needed either. :)

Comment: My mistake has been to include the case of $S=F=n$ which is clearly impossible, I updated the formula. The incomplete beta functions are there to ensure that $\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} \mathbb{P}(N_n =k) = 1$

Comment: The incomplete beta functions are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood this correctly, but:

A trial ends either in success or failure. Assuming it was a success after $k$ trials, we know we had $n$ successes and $k-n$ failures, so the probability of this happening would rather be

$$ P(S_n=k) = {{k}\choose{n}} (1-p)^{k-n}p^n.$$

Furthermore, note that the successes and failures scenarios are mutually exclusive. There is no way you can reorder the trials and change the issue for a given $S_n$ or $F_n$.

So, shouldn't you rather have

$$ P(N_n=k) = P(S_n=k) + P(F_n=k) $$

given that $S_n=k$ and $F_n=k$ refer to opposite, mutually exclusive scenarii ?

Finally, observe that for $k=2n-1$, there is automatic (still mutually exclusive) success or failure, so you can completely characterize the distribution for $k \in [n,2n-1]$

Comment: @bofh I first attempted to go this route, but it is easy to verify that $\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} P(N_n =k) \not 1$. For instance for $n=3$ and $p=1/2$, I get $\sum _{k=n}^{2 n-1} \binom{k}{n} \left((1-p)^n p^{n-k}+p^n (1-p)^{k-n}\right)=\frac{109}{16}$.

Comment: @Sasha: Try with ${k-1 \choose n-1}$ instead of ${k \choose n}$. It is trivially true that $\sum_{k=n}^{2n - 1} \mathbb P(N_n = k) = 1$. (Why?) :)

Comment: @cardinal I realized that in my approach the normalization factor is also a hidden unity, and added a note to that effect. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Yep, I lacked coffe and completely missed the point indeed. Sorry for the noise :)